# Visual Studio 2005 Project options

Tags: visual-studio-2005, projects

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2005(professional Edition) which in turn has 8 projects.I am facing a problem that even after i set the Command Arguments in the Project settings of the relevant project, it doesnt accept those command line arguments and it shows argc = 1, inspite of me giving more than 1 command arguments. Tried making the settings of this Solution similar to a working solution, but no success. 
Any pointers?

-Ajit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. Are you sure the specified project is set as the start project (right click > set as startup project) ??

Oh, and obviously you need to be in the correct configuration mode ^_^

(Notice it can be changed to *debug | build | all configurations* )

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are setting the command arguments on the same configuration (Debug|Release) you are debugging? As far as I remember command arguments are per configuration.